# Reading multiple user input strings inside a loop

Tags: c

I am currently trying to solve a problem from CodeChef but I am having troubles with using fgets() inside a loop.

The first input (T) is going to be a positive integer containing the number of user inputs.
Then delimited by newline characters, the user is going to input a string below the length of 10 under any circumstances.

So, I've tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int T;
    int diffX, diffY;
    char s[SIZE];

    scanf("%d", &T);

    while (T--){
        fgets(s, SIZE, stdin);
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I attempted to test the code  with the following inputs:

> 3 
> Hello
>  Hi
>  What

I was only able to input until "Hi" then the program exited successfully (returning 0).

Why is this the case and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance,
kpark.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't consume the `\n` from the user entered number.  You need to first consume this

Comment: Suggest avoid using both `scanf()` with `fgets()`.  BTW: Nice tight example of your problem.

Comment: It takes three strings.  The first one consists of just the newline after the 3 (because the `scanf()` leaves the newline behind).  Then you have `Hello` and `Hi` as numbers 2 and 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets()` consumes the newline left behind by the first call to `scanf()`. So, it is consuming 3 lines, but the first line looks like an empty line to the `fgets()` loop you have.

You can fix this by using `fgets()` to get the first line too, and parse the string into a number using `sscanf()`.

```
fgets(s, SIZE, stdin);
sscanf(s, "%d", &T);
/* ... */
```

Comment: This has worked well for me and learned a new function. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is counting the read of the T as part of the counting.  Add a newline in the scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10



    int main()
    {
        int T;
        int diffX, diffY;
        char s[SIZE];

        scanf("%d\n", &T);

        while (T--){
            fgets(s, SIZE, stdin);
            printf("%s\n", s);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Adding the newline to the `scanf()` format will work OK here, but would be horrid if the user was typing because the `scanf()` would not return until some other non-white-space input was entered after the number.  Better to use `fgets()` for all inputs, and `sscanf()` to process the number.

Comment: This has worked for me and the advice from Jonathan was informative. Thank you!

Comment: I agree with Jonathan.  Just trying to change the code minimally.

Comment: This does not perform consistently is the first time `fgets()` is called has leading spaces as compare to subsequent calls.  If you want to scan in a single '\n`, use "%*[\n]".  Recall that '\n' in a `scanf()` format matches any number of any white space.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Question is about **how to read Multiple Strings in C ?**
Then it can be done by 2 ways :-
**1.By declaring two dimensional Array of characters.**

```
//Let say we want 6 strings each of them having max 10 characters.
char set[6][10] ;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
scanf("%s",set[i])
```

**2.By declaring one dimensional Array of pointers to character (Notice the naming Conventions), in which each of those pointer pointing to a String.**

```
int main(){

int i,numOfStrings;
char temp[30];

printf("Enter Number of strings in set ");
scanf("%d",&numOfStrings);

//Here We have defined array of pointer that will store each string sepratly.
//Arry of pointer to character.
char *setOfStrings[numOfStrings];

for(i=0;i<numOfStrings;i++)
{
    printf("Enter string ");
    scanf("%s",temp);
    setOfStrings[i]= (char*)malloc(sizeof(temp)); //allocted new memory and gave it to array of pointer
    strcpy(setOfStrings[i],temp);
}

for(i=0;i<numOfStrings;i++)
{
    printf("string = %s \n",setOfStrings[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

**But that need to understand :**
In case of array of pointers we may initialize them with String but **Can't take as input from Command line** like

```
char *set[2]={"Dinesh","Kandpal"}; //Its valid but you can't do this from command line
```

for doing so What we do we will create an space dynamically ,s**tore that address in the one of the element in 1-D array of pointers and then whatever value we have scanned copy that content to the another string to the location that we created using malloc**